# VBA Excel Book to Book copy cell value not formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed (with help from stackoverflow user:  @xificurC ) a VBA macro in excel that copies over a certain range of cells and pastes them, in a table in a seperate workbook. But there are formula on these tables that are relating to pieces of data that are not available with the user permissions on my account. So my question is how can I copy over the actual face values of the cells instead of the formula.

```
    'get all excel files (and only excel files) from specified folder
    file_checks = Dir(path & "\*.xls*")
     Do Until file_checks = ""
      'open file
       Set wkbklp = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & file_checks)
       Set wkshtlp = wkbklp.Sheets(1)
      'copy data away from original
       Set data_return = wkshtlp.Range(start_cell).CurrentRegion
       data_return.Copy check_sheet.Cells(check_sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      'close file without saving to make it all more automated
       wkbklp.Close False
      'loop through files until all are done
       file_checks = Dir
    Loop
```

That was the code that transfers the data from one book to another. I have not found a command that does this, but I'm only amateur so may have used the wrong key words.

Comment: Just use **Copy** and **PasteSpecial** values

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I am not sure how to use that, have you got a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using pastespecial.

```
   data_return.Copy
   check_sheet.Cells(check_sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pastespecial method, I don't see where are you pasting but it will be something like

```
Range.PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues
```