# VBA Excel Copy Table Values only to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy only the values from a table to a different sheet, however the below code is only copying the formulas thus losing references. I have tried different solutions such as adding .Value to .DataBodyRange.Copy Cells(i,1) however didn't work.

Thanks for your help

```
Sub loadData()
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
Dim wsh As Worksheet, i&
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then .Range.AutoFilter
    .DataBodyRange.Delete
    i = 4
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsh.Name <> "Template"  Then
            With wsh.ListObjects(4)
                .DataBodyRange.Copy Cells(i, 1)
                i = i + .ListRows.Count
            End With
        End If
    Next wsh
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=5
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub    `
```

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699690/vba-excel-book-to-book-copy-cell-value-not-formula) might help you. Try changing the format (values or formulas) when pasting the values using pastespecial.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using loops to accomplish your checks.  You should use loops to finish the job and don't worry about using the clipboard to copy and paste.  I can understand using copy and paste especially if you don't understand loops, but you clearly do.

You can do another loop where you set the values for the cells one at a time.

```
LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'Get last column of row with data

For col = 1 To LastCol
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, col).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, col).Value
Next col
```

This isn't a complete solution, but if you insert this into your code where you are trying to copy and paste, you should get a good idea of how to complete this.  Again, I'd avoid using copy and paste macros, simply because it's quicker to just write a three or four line loop in VBA than to record a macro, then edit it, clean it up, modify it, and debug it.  It sure seems like less work to "record a macro" but in my experience, the code is quicker and more accurate.  You know exactly what is happening instead of some parameters you might not want to question and don't know what they do.